# How to count number of arguments?

Tags: java, arguments, command-line-arguments, argument-passing

Can any one tell me how can I count number of arguments in java.

I am using log4j and below is the code I am using but still I see that my code stucks at length =0 . Any help?

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws RemoteException{

  log.info("running Example1");

  String sfUrl = "https://ca...ov";
  String sfUser ="...";
  String sfPass ="...";

  log.error(args.length);



  if (args.length != 3)
  {
     log.error("Usage: teamforge-url username password");
  }
  else
  {
     sfUrl  = args[0];
     sfUser = args[1];
     sfPass = args[2];
```

Comment: How are you calling the main method? If you're not calling it with any arguments, than 0 is to be expected.

Comment: `args.length` is the correct way. Why it stays at 0 probably because due to how it is called.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running this from an IDE, you must configure some running options on your project, maybe you just forgotten it. Just saying, because args.length is the correct way.